# Executing SQL against AS400 specifying *LIBL rather than a specific library

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ibm-midrange

I have a requirement to perform basic SQL (an insert, in this case) against a file on the AS400.  I'm writing a thick client, command line app in C# running on Windows 2008.

If I specify a library and a file as follows:

```
insert into somelibrary.somefile (col1,col2) values val1,val2
```

then it works.  The problem is that the value of `somelibrary` will differ between users and environments.  I'd like to use the library list *LIBL, so that it will pick up on whatever libraries that user has been allocated, in the correct order.  I'd like to avoid having to use configuration files, if possible.

The user I'm testing with has, in his library list, the library which contains `somefile`. If I try:

```
insert into somefile (col1,col2...) values val1,val2
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - somefile in username type *FILE not found.
```

I've tried adding *LIBL in the SQL, and also in the connection string, but it's not finding the file.  I've tried quite a few combinations, as well as using slashes to separate the library and the file.

In case it's relevant the connection string is:

```
Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)}; System=" + server + "; UID=" + DBUser + "; PWD=" + DBPassword + ";";
```

Comment: Does this query work when run via iSeries? (I had an AS400 SQL Reference manual at my old job.. literally 3 months ago!)

Comment: Yes, works fine from there.

Comment: Try adding `Naming Convention=1` to your connection string to switch into *SYS naming mode.

Comment: No change. Is that the same as 'naming=system' in the connection string?  And should I add *LIBL somewhere in the connection string as well? (I've just tried a few variations here but might have missed one!).

Comment: dmc: Seems that my driver is fussy and only 'naming=1' will do (not 'naming=system' or 'naming convention=1'.  Cheers!

Comment: @Poldie. You could also change at ODBC setup at Server Tab, you can change Naming Convention and set Library list: to *usrlibl . I prefer to use .Net provider. For .Net provider use Naming=System;LibraryList=*USRLIBL;SchemaSearchList=*USRLIBL

Comment: lamLam: What is "Server Tab"?

Comment: It where you define your ODBC. From windows control panel ->Administrative tools ->Data Source (ODBC). Select your Data source name, then in second tab - Server tab

Comment: lamLam: I didn't do that.  No DSN or ODBC configuration. I installed Client Access and use the drivers from there.  This app will get installed on a number of servers and I always try to avoid having to add entries to the registry or make manual changes to individual boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library list used for this request is the library list of the user profile used to authenticate against.  The user profile points to two items that are interesting with respect to the library list: the Job Description and the Initial Program.  Check the job description to see what the library list is.  Probably, it won't have the library containing SOMEFILE.  That leaves the initial program.  If the library list is set in the initial program, you have a problem, because the initial program is only executed when the profile signs on to a terminal session.

The way around this is to create a user profile and job description that has the library list you need.

Comment: The job description does contain SOMELIBRARY (which contains SOMEFILE).  And I'm running an insert statement via a C# app, not using a terminal session, so I'm not sure that the initial program is invoked.

Comment: Well, one down.  If you are getting the error message that SOMEFILE in USERNAME not found then you are using the SQL naming convention rather than SYSTEM.  IBM [support document 9951625](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/2554db904e5a601b862565c2007cc4b8?OpenDocument) describes the situation.

Comment: I'm marking this as the winning answer - the solution was adding 'naming=1'. Before I even posted my question I tried 'naming=system' which didn't work. It seems now that this is a jdbc thing only and doesn't work with the Client Access ODBC Driver.  Many thanks!